# Got AuthorizedOnly when pulling images behind corporate proxy

Tags: docker, proxy

I’ve trying to get docker working behind a corporate proxy. Following the document here:
     https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy

Basically adding:

```
[Service]
Environment=“HTTP_PROXY=http://[username]:[password]@127.0.0.1:3128/”
```

under

```
/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf
```

Restart docker and all.

But when running “docker pull hello-world” or “sudo docker pull hello-world”, got this error:

```
centos7 ~]$ docker pull hello-world
Using default tag: latest
Trying to pull repository docker. io/library/hello-world …
Pulling repository docker. io/library/hello-world
Error while pulling image: Get https: 
/index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/hello-world/images: AuthorizedOnly
```

Looks around the web, but couldn’t find any “AuthorizedOnly” error reported before.

```
docker -v
Docker version 1.12.6, build 3e8e77d/1.12.6
```

Any hints/help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue: It's not the problem with docker proxy configuration. It was the proxy itself that blocks hub.docker.com.

To resolve this particular problem, I have use a different proxy with less restrictions.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your enterprise proxy URL.

- Usually, an enterprise proxy does not reside on localhost (127.0.0.1), but on a specific IP address.
- Usually, `HTTPS_PROXY` needs to be set as well (to the same HTTP URL)
- Usually, `NO_PROXY` needs to be set, at least to localhost, to avoid contacting the proxy for *every* remote query.

Comment: This is a local proxy running with cntlm, so the IP wasnt the issue. Found the issue now, silly as it sounds but the proxy is blocking hub.docker.com (!!! yes). To resolve it, I have to use a more liberal proxy. The docker proxy configuration is good, no issue with it.

Comment: To add another point, you are absolutely right about the corporate proxies. It is just the setup here is more or less custom for a virtualbox image, where cntlm is used to "centralise" all proxy configurations and credentials management as well.

Comment: @tuan.dinh OK. Interesting setup.